# How to read/load a JSON file in Typescript

Tags: json, typescript

I am quite New to Typescript and I am trying to read a simple JSON file from typescript. I have googled and tried but I just need a simple code lines that read a local json file into a nummeric array variable. The json file is like [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 16.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4].

If someone can help me out on this, I would be very Grateful

Regards gf

Comment: Can you elaborate on "read a JSON file from TypeScript"? Where is the JSON file? Where is your TypeScript running? Parsing a JSON string is just a matter of using [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). Loading a JSON file is a different question and depends on where and how you want to load a file.

Comment: hi again. well the question was how to load the json file and to make it ready into a varable. the data is to be used as input to a bar chart. in javascript I can usj

Comment: use getjson. but even how I try I can't get the json file loaded in typescript. the json file is by now local in my visual studio project. I guess I may ne

Comment: need to import some library before I can start working on the json file. hope I explained more  clearly. and iphone is no good tool to use to comment

Answer (score 0):

### First create a JSON file under a folder e.g. properties.json.

```
{ 
"url" : "https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/package.json?msclkid=3b7f06f5d0e111eca3cc1f08a914ff77",
person: {
   "firstname":"yuvraj",
   "lastname" : "thorat"
}
}
```

---

### and then read the JSON file, need to create a file inside your project folder.
readjson.ds.ts

```
declare module "*.json" {
   const value : any;
   export default value
}
```

---

now you can access this JSON date inside your project in different file.

you have to add import statement as below and then json properties.

```
---------------------------------------------------
import * as prop from "../testdata/properties.json"

siteUrl =  (<any>prop).url;
----------------------------------------------------
```

That's all, you should be able access all remaining properties similar way.

Comment: this has been worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

Standard Javascript -

```
var json = "[29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 16.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]";
var arr = JSON.parse(json);
```

(edit)

Just noticed the "local file" bit - if you mean at compile time then you need to prefix the JSON (in the file) with the variable name an then nothing else needs doing - quite literally a simple `window.json = ...` works - there's no need for quotes etc. If it's at runtime then it needs to be loaded either via AJAX, or - again - via prefixing with a variable name and adding the file in a `<script type="text/javascript" src="file.json"></script>` tag.